# How does React's state hold files through use of spread operator?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, file, state

My understanding in with `[...files]` is that it'll create a reference to the file objects, but how can state just hold references?

```
  handleChange = (e) => {
    const { onChange } = this.props;
    const files = this.getFileFromInput(e);

    onChange && onChange(e);

    this.setState(() => ({
      files: [...files],
    }));
  }
```

Comment: _how can state just hold references_ What exactly do you mean?

Comment: `this.state` itself is just a reference - it references an object which, in turn, references other objects (like file objects) or primitives (like strings, booleans, numbers, etc).

Comment: As far as I understand, if `files` is an array with three elements, then `...files` is equivalent to `files[0], files[1], files[2]`.

Comment: @ChrisG - could also be an object - we'd have to see what `getFileFromInput` returns. If it returned an array then it'd be silly to do `files:[...files]` when you could just do `files:files` so I'm guessing it returns an object.

Answer (score 1):

When you spread an array into another array, it returns a new array, with references to the old one. The spread syntax used in this manner is meant to replace `Object.assign`. This works for objects and arrays. These are functionally equivalent:

```
[...files]
Object.assign([], files)
```